# Display The Names of All Excel Data Models in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to display the names of my DataModels in my workbook.

I defined model as object

```
For Each model In ThisWorkbook.model.WorkbookDataModels
```

I get

> object doesn't support this property or method

I have Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library checked in the references.
I am using Excel 365.

```vb
Sub ShowDataModels()
    Dim model As Object
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rel As Object
    
    For Each model In ThisWorkbook.model.WorkbookDataModels
        Debug.Print "Data Model Name: " & model.ModelName
        Debug.Print "  Tables:"
        
        For Each tbl In model.ModelTables
            Debug.Print "    " & tbl.Name
        Next tbl
        
        Debug.Print "  Relationships:"
        
        For Each rel In model.ModelRelationships
            Debug.Print "    " & rel.FromTable.Name & " -> " & rel.ToTable.Name
        Next rel
    Next model
End Sub
```

Comment: A [`Model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.model) object has no `.WorkbookDataModels` property?

Answer (score 0):

You would enumerate ThisWorkbook.model.**ModelTables**, not WorkbookDataModels.

I think you might just be mixing up the concept of the overarching model with all the objects in it.

An Excel workbook contains only one DataModel, which can have multiple tables.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was wondering about that. Ultimately what I am trying to do is to dump a 13 million row query to a single .csv file.

Comment: Ok now I am trying the following in EXCEL 365:  'Get reference to query table and its expression
    Set modelTable = ThisWorkbook.model.ModelTables(1)
    Set queryTable = modelTable.GetQueryTable("Query - DEMOXX") - I am getting doesn't support property or method error in the 2nd. line. Is 'GetQueryTable' not a method of ModelTable?

Comment: Take some time to read how StackOverflow works at https://stackoverflow.com/tour, consider accepting my initial response as the answer, and post a new question. Not being snarky - it's just that SO only works because the community follows strict guidelines. It's not a discussion forum.